# change image by click and un-click button for iphone?

Tags: ios, image, uibutton

This question for iphone app
Hi, i was trying to make an small task:

1. the default interface has an image and 2 buttons,
2. when you clicked on the button, it changed the image and the button remain clicked (selected i think)
3. when i press on the button again, the image go back to the original image.
4. If i pressed 2 buttons, it changes to another new image saying both buttons were pressed.

I was able to reach step 2 but i don't know how to do it for step 3 and 4. can someone help me out please? Here is the code i got so far:

on viewcontroller.h

```
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController - (IBAction)buttonPressedRight:(UIButton *)sender;

    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label
```

and on viewcontroller.m, the code the same for both buttons.

```
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *title = [sender titleForState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ button pressed.",title];

    _label.text = newText;
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"num1.png"] ;
    _imageView.image = image1;

    sender.selected = !sender.selected;
}
```

Comment: Are you using same action event for both buttons?

Comment: Yes i'm using same event for both buttons

Answer (score 0):

Just like a physical button when you pressed it(selected) before it return back you can not press it again.

So to achieve the `3.when i press on the button again, the image go back to the original image.` you should not make your button selected when pressed. Instead you can change the button's appearance and title to indicate the button is now selected.

I think this applies to 4.xxxx too